# Prestashop is not defined on index page

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I have a weird bug with my **prestashop 1.7.4.3**, but I wouldn't like to reinstall it so im writing here.
There are like 20 errors in console on homepage, but the main one is -

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: prestashop is not defined".

I don't know why, but JQuery is not loading too. The problem is that it is only happening at the homepage. On subpages or product pages there is everything alright (and this prestashop var is also initialized). I was searching through the code for like 2 hours and couldn't find anything that is cause. Many features at homepages are not working (slider, menu on mobile version etc.). These features work on other pages than index.
If anyone knows what could it be or how to fix it, I will appreciate it

Comment: please show us , other errors, do you use the native theme ?

Comment: I use Pixtron theme, the other errors are almost the same
-Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
-Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
-Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

it's like JQuery and this prestashop var is not loading on frontpage. On other pages it works all just fine.

Comment: first try to use the native theme and see if errors still there, if not, means the bug is located in your Pixtron theme. so secondly try to desactivate ovveride and finally try to desactivate module by module, it looks like a Javascript conflict